# Optimizing Apache 2.4 performance on Windows for serving a single file

Tags: performance, apache, tomcat, optimization, webserver

I run a webpage for a non-profit charity project. It's pure HTML / CSS delivered per proxypass ajp from a Tomcat "behind" the Apache. No images included, so it's just the html request, even css is delivered from another server.

Apache mpm is configured with 1100 threads per child.

It's ok up to 50 requests per second, then the performance starts to drop drastically. The server is still fine from a memory and CPU perspective. So I am looking for options.

- Would it make sense to setup a second Apache on the same server and
  balance between both, so is there a restriction, because I only run
  one instance?
- Would it be faster to generate static html pages and let them serve
  without proxy pass to tomcat (tomcat seems to have no issues, is
  still fast under load)?
- Any typical performance hints?

Thanks a lot

Tomcat runs on port 8080, ajp is used to communicate with Apache.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="60000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Can you add Tomcat's configuration parameters, e.g. number of working threads? If the pages don't change too frequently, the Apache HTTP Server can [cache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/caching.html) the responses.

Comment: Where can I find the Tomcat configuration parameter? Would you say it's more a Tomcat than a Apache problem? Tomcat runtimes are milliseconds.

Comment: Please, add the `server.xml` file to your question. By default Tomcat has 200 working threads, If there is a bottleneck, it is probably more on Tomcat's side than on Apache's side.

Comment: You should serve static pages directly from Apache HTTPD without proxying to Tomcat at all. Off topic.

Comment: If the html file is not dynamic, forget Tomcat, serve it directly from Apache.  You have a high number of threads per child, you do realize that each of those will hit your tomcat?  Gut feeling, you are killing your tomcat with too many requests.  Use apache status to see how your mpm is doing.  Reducing the "entry" might be beneficial, make the clients wait as far forward as possible.  You should post your apache mpm config, there are more parameters than just threads per child.

Comment: File is partly dynamic, so that's why I need Tomcat in the back. Could I raise AJP threadcount or what would be the suggested?

Comment: MPM is doing well, most of the times under load it's 800 out of 1100 in use. Maybe I have to adjust AJP settings.